# What is wrong with my method of finding the size of matrix A in $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A be an $m x n$ matrix and suppose the $\dim \text{Nul}(A)=3$.
>
> Suppose that there is some $b ∈ \mathbb{R}^5$ such that $\text{rank}[A\ b] =4$. What size must $A$ be for the equation $Ax = b$ to be consistent?

**My Thoughts:**

Now, we know that $b$ is a $1$ x $5$ matrix. And we know from elementary mathematics that for matrix multiplication to occur for example:

$Ax=b$

If A is $\color{purple}{m}$ x $\color{orange}{n}$, then x must be of the form $\color{orange}{n}$ x $\color{purple}{d}$. Which will make b as $\color{purple}{m \text{ x } d}$

We know that b is 1 x 5 which implies that A is 1 x n.

Now all we need to do is find m, and we can use the formula :

rank (A) + dim Nul(A)= n

$\implies n=4+3=7$

**So, A must be 1 x 7. But this is obviously wrong, because I can't imagine A to have only 1 column.** What is wrong with my work?

Comment: $b$ is $5\times1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Oh so the matrix A has a size of 5 x 7. Is this method approach right? :)

Comment: @M.S.E Yeah, it looks right. The only thing when you say $1\times 7$ having only one column: $1\times 7$ has one *row*. And it is obviously wrong because the rank is at most one, not $4$, in this case.

Comment: @A.G. got it :)